# How to setup default document for a IIS website from command prompt?

Tags: iis, web

I want to set default document for a IIS website from command prompt.

May I know how to setup this..

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use appcmd.exe:

```
 appcmd set config /section:defaultDocument /enabled:true|false

Check appcmd help at MSDN (or here) for more information.
```

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

Comment: Do we have any alternative for IIS 5.0??